# Передать байтовый массив изображения через Intent в другую Activity

Tags: java, android

Есть первая Activity в которой получается изображение с камеры.Затем передается в другую Activity для дальнейшей обработки:

```
public void SendMyPicture(byte[] data){
        String msg = "size byte[] =  " + data.length + " !";
        Toast.makeText(this, msg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // передача картинки в другую активность
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, BtmTakeActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra(BtmTakeActivity.PICTURE_DATA, data);
          startActivity(intent);
}
```

Проблема: при размере массива 2.2 МБайт передача не проходит. 40 КБайт все работает.
Проверил  available Memory ~300 мГб

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ActivityManager.MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
        activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

        totalMemory = memoryInfo.totalMem;
        availableMemory = memoryInfo.availMem;
        //InfoMain1="  ";
        InfoMain1="TotalMemory = " + (int)totalMemory/(1024 *1024) + " : AvailableMemory = " + (int)availableMemory/(1024*1024)
```

В чем может быть проблема? Да, Bitmap не открываю!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На передачу данных через Bundle есть лимит - `1Mb`. Вот цитата из [доки](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles):

> The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1MB, which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process. Since this limit is at the process level rather than at the per activity level, these transactions include all binder transactions in the app such as onSaveInstanceState, startActivity and any interaction with the system. When the size limit is exceeded, a TransactionTooLargeException is thrown.

В этой же доке сказано, что ошибка `TransactionTooLargeException` будет кидаться только после 7 версии ОС включительно. До этой версии будет вывод ошибки в логи и непередача данных:

> Note: In Android 7.0 (API level 24) and higher, the system throws a TransactionTooLargeException as a runtime exception. In lower versions of Android, the system only shows a warning in logcat.

---

Соответственно, пытаться передавать BitMap через Bundle - неработающая в реальной жизни идея. Надо записывать BitMap в файл и передавать путь до этого файла, чтобы в целевой актвити получать Bitmap из этого файла.

---

В качестве нерекомендуемого (в большинстве случаев) решения (из-за возможных OOM Exceptions и лишнего расхода оперативки и сложности поддержки корректной) можно сохранить BitMap в глобальную переменную (Singleton) - тогда её и передавать никуда не надо.