# Как можно передать ArrayList<Drawable> в другую активити?

Tags: java, android

Как можно передать ArrayList в другую активити?

Comment: В интент они скорее всего не поместятся, через синглтон - плохое решение и по-моему `Drawable` контексто-зависим. Лучше пересмотреть подход к задаче так, чтобы делать этого не пришлось.

Comment: Используй класс отдельный, и обращайся к нему из активити всех

Comment: Посмотрите тут ответ почему не стоит делать то, что вы хотите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1254203/17609